# how to put the result from memory to a file *.txt

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, malloc, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to implement a matrix multiplication program with 2 files as an arguments (mat1.txt and mat2.txt). I decided to load the result in a file, but when I execute the program: ./m mat1.txt mat2.txt 20 20 20 20 (filenames and number of rows and columns of every matrix), I obtain and error: Segmentation fault (core dumped).
The problem is with the file result creation or writing, Could you help me?
The code is presented below:

```
 /* Memory management */
mem_mat1 = (int *) malloc(M1 * N1 * sizeof(int));
if (mem_mat1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: malloc mem_mat1\n");
    /*MPI_Finalize();*/
    return (3);
}

mat1 = (int **) malloc(M1 *sizeof(int *));
if (mat1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: malloc mat1\n");
    /*MPI_Finalize();*/
    return (3);
} 

for (i=0; i<M1; i++) {
    mat1[i] = mem_mat1+(i*N1);
}

mem_mat2 = (int *) malloc(M2 * N2 * sizeof(int));
if (mem_mat2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: mem_mat2\n");
    /*MPI_Finalize();*/
    return (3);
}

mat2 = (int **) malloc(M2 *sizeof(int *));
if (mat2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: malloc mat2\n");
    /*MPI_Finalize();*/
    return (3);
} 

for (i=0; i<M2; i++) {
    mat2[i] = mem_mat2+(i*N2);
}

mem_matR = (int *) malloc(M1 * N2 * sizeof(int));
if (mem_matR == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: malloc mem_matR\n");
    /*MPI_Finalize();*/
    return (3);
}

matR = (int **) malloc(M1 *sizeof(int *));
if (matR == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: malloc matR\n");
    /*MPI_Finalize();*/
    return (3);
}

for (i=0; i<M1; i++) {
    matR[i] = mem_matR+(i*N2);
}

/* SEQUENTIAL PRODUCT MATRIX */

/*Open and Read file 1: mat1.txt*/
fmat1 = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
fread(mat1, M1 *sizeof(int *), N1 *sizeof(int *), fmat1);

/*Open and Read file 2: mat2.txt*/
fmat2 = fopen(argv[2],"rb");
fread(mat2, M2 *sizeof(int *), N2 *sizeof(int *), fmat2);

/*Create a file to write the result fmatR.txt*/
fdR = creat("matR.txt", "w");
if (fdR < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error create result file\n");
    return(2);
}

for (i=0;i<M1;i++) {
    for (j=0;j<N2;j++) {
        sum=0;
        for (k=0;k<N1;k++) {
            sum+=mat1[i][k]*mat2[k][j];
            matR[i][j]=sum;
        }
    }
 }
 write(fdR, &matR, M1*N2 *sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Where is the seg-fault?  What steps have you taken to narrow it down or isolate it?

Comment: First,remove cast from `malloc()`..

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This is not a debugging service. If you want to debug, use a debugger.

Comment: For a start, the second parameter of `creat` is incorrect, it should probably be `O_WRONLY`.

Comment: Other hints:  you are not checking the returns from `fopen`, `fread`, or `write`.  You might find `perror()` useful for error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're doing some mess with matR writing random memory... also the last line is wrong.

Fix:

1) take away **mem_matR** and all the code related to it

2) let **matR** be a pointer to the first element of the matrix (your buffer) and let it be a simple one dimension array of M1xN2 elements

```
matR = (int *) malloc( M1 * N2 * sizeof(int));
```

3) in the for loop at the end write matR this way

```
matR[j+i*N2]=sum;
```

4) finally save the data this way

```
write(fdR, (void *) matR, M1*N2 *sizeof(int));
```

--

also I think the fread calls are wrong (even if this doesn't cause issues)

```
fread(mat1, M1 *sizeof(int *), N1 *sizeof(int *), fmat1);
```

if I understand you have a martix of M1 x N1 elements that are integer. so...

```
fread(mat1, sizeof(int *), M1 * N1, fmat1);
```

same applies to the secon call